# Remove duplicate value from Drop down

Tags: jquery

I need to remove the duplicate values from the drop down list, please advise:

```
var schoolDropDown = $('#schoolDropDown');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: NMUSDDataURL + "API/RequestService.asmx/GetSites",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        var schools = response.d;
        $('#output').empty();
        $.each(schools, function (index, school) {
            schoolDropDown.append($("<option />").val(school.RecordID).text(school.Schools));
        });
    },

    failure: function (msg) {
        $('#output').text(msg);
    }

});
```

Comment: Just check to see if you have already added an option with the drop down value, either using a list/obj that contains all the already added values or simply by checking  `schoolDropDown`  for the existence of options with the values before you add them. What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: Thank you, worked great!

Answer (score 0):

Create a `sampleArray` check every time if the `Schools` is in `array` or not, if not then push in `array` and append in the list. This way you can remove duplicates.

```
var sampleArray = [];
$.each(schools, function(index, school) {

  // Check if Schools is already in sampleArray
  if (sampleArray.indexOf(school.Schools) == -1) {
    schoolDropDown.append($("<option />").val(school.RecordID).text(school.Schools));
    // Push if unique
    sampleArray.push(school.Schools);
  }
});
```

I am checking for `school.Schools`, if you want to do a check for `school.RecordID` then just change the property name in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a temp array and store the items to it as you loop through it. And before adding to your dropdown, check against the temp array to see whether it is already added. If not added already , add it to temp array and append to the dropdown. You may use the `$.inArray` method.

```
var itemsAdded=[];
$.each(schools, function (index, school) {

   if($.inArray(school.RecordID,itemsAdded)===-1) 
   {
      itemsAdded.push(school.RecordID);
      schoolDropDown.append($("<option/>").val(school.RecordID).text(school.Schools));
   }
});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/luwiti/edit?js,console,output) is a working sample.